# Call python code asynchronously from c api

Tags: python, c++, asynchronous, embed

Sorry for noob question i really new in async programming and python embedding

I embed python in my c++ application via c api. But then i calling something like `time.sleep(10)` it freezes my interface (because i waiting for `PyEval_EvalCode`)

Are there beautiful way to execute some python code async and fetch result using python threading?

Sorry for my poor English

Comment: Also looking for this.  Would like control to return to the caller if python attempts blocking I/O, preferably with a fd for the I/O operation that can be select()'d on.